# Make custom user functions Enable and Disable in Wordpress Admin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new to WP development, and I need some basic help. I want to find a way to implement new user functions Enable/Disable on user accounts inside WP Admin CMS.

[image]

So, I have Edit and Delete function for this User. How can I add here Enable and Disable function with my own Mysql code that will update his user_status ? I suppose I can do a simple add_filter , but how exactly ? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To add more actions, you can use `user_row_actions` filter. For example:

```
add_filter('user_row_actions', 'my_handler');
function my_handler($links, $user)
{
    $links['soft_delete'] = '<span class="blahblah" data-user-id="' . $user->ID . '">Do some stuff</span>';
    return $links;
}
```

Then, have some JS code send an ajax request to handle the action.
If you want to have `.js` file only loaded for users page, you can do the following:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_scripts');

function add_my_scripts()
{
    global $current_screen;
    if ((!defined('DOING_AJAX') || !DOING_AJAX) && $current_screen->id == 'users')
    {
            wp_enqueue_script('my_script', 'url_to_your_js_file', array('jquery'), false, true);
            wp_localize_script('my_script', 'my_ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php', ((is_ssl()) ? 'https' : 'http'))));   
    }
}
```

[Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_row_actions/)